# Как переводить "people reached"?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

[Обсуждение на Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/137096) даёт контекст и относительную важность термина.

[Пример использования](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded).
Текущая подсказка из примера:

> Estimated number of times people
>   viewed your helpful posts (based on
>   page views of your questions and
>   questions where you wrote
>   highly-ranked answers)

Варианты из [чата](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20369685#20369685):

```
2,505 answers, 84 questions, ~1.5m people reached = 
 2505 ответов,  84 вопросов, ~1.5м охват аудитории =
 2505 ответов,  84 вопросов, ~1.5м просмотров = 
 2505 ответов,  84 вопросов, ~1.5м людей помог = 
 2505 ответов,  84 вопросов, ~1.5м людей достиг = 
 2505 ответов,  84 вопросов, ~1.5м людей коснулся = 
 2505 ответов,  84 вопросов, ~1.5м людей затронул
```

- «охват аудитории» -- слова, которые можно услышать при обсуждении рекламной компании.
- «просмотров» -- идею полезности вопросов/ответов не передаёт
- «помог»:

> Calling it <s>"Bunnies and Puppies Saved
>   by Hugs"</s> **"People Helped"** is, at a
>   minimum, a little distracting, and at
>   worst, makes us "Filthy, evil liars."
>   Okay, no one quite said that. But
>   almost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант.*

«**людей затронул**»

---

*Остальные варианты.*

- «охват аудитории».
- «просмотров».
- «людей помог».
- «людей достиг».
- «людей коснулся».
- «полезных ответов».