# Количество людей, затронутых пользователем

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация

В профиле пользователя существует блок с числом людей, которых затронул пользователь.

> Примерное число раз, когда посетители видели ваши полезные сообщения (считается на основе просмотров ваших вопросов и высоко оцененных ответов)

У тех, кто ведет на сайте активную деятельность эти число исчисляется тысячами, а то и миллионами. И блок в данном случае выглядит вполне корректно:

[image: 2к]

Однако, для новых пользователей это число невелико и блок выглядит довольно странно:

[image: 23] [image: 24] [image: 161]

В данном случае было бы уместнее использовать существительное "человек" с учетом правильного числа.

Предлагаю определиться с какими количествами какую форму стоит использовать, чтобы это звучало по-русски.

Дополнительные материалы по теме:

- [вопрос о переводе термина "people reached"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/447/176217)
- [ссылка на чат с обсуждением этого перевода](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20369685#20369685)

Comment: "жалких людишек"

Comment: @Abyx такую форму можно вставлять на 1 апреля например

Comment: Мне всегда казалось, что "примерно" здесь означает, что невозможно точно знать, затронули вы этого человека или он случайно остановил прокрутку на вашем ответе и пошёл наливать чай.

Comment: @NewDevelop я вообще не уверен, что можно узнать было ли сообщение видно на экране или нет, даже если открыта страница с этим сообщением. Но вопрос несколько о другом.

Comment: Вы не пытались искать предыдущие обсуждения на эту тему? Есть ли в transifex ссылка на обсуждение? (Чтобы не повторять аргументы или наоборот их изменить из-за накопленного опыта)

Comment: @jfs ссылка в transifex на обсуждение? Не очень Вас понял.

Comment: @alexolut в transifex должна быть запись для фразы "people reached" Так как перевод неочевиден, то я мог ссылку там оставить на обсуждение на хэшкоде или здесь в чате/на Мете (не помню), чтобы люди на одни и те же грабли не наступали при изменении перевода.

Comment: @jfs там есть две ссылки: одна на [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20369685#20369685), вторая на какой-то [вопрос](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/3374/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-people-reached) о комментариях. Видимо что-то съехало.

Comment: Вы в свой вопрос добавьте (со своим summary), чтобы другим людям было легче найти, если найдёте. Ссылка из вашего комментария левая какая-то. Можете не искать, забывать тоже может быть полезно, но интернет без памяти  не построишь.

Comment: @jfs ссылки скопированы из transifex как есть. Я сразу сказал, видимо что-то съехало при переезде с хэш на мета.so. Собственно в чате (по первой ссылке) есть как раз и вторая (побитая) ссылка на вопрос с голосованием.

Comment: @jfs теперь должны видеть

Comment: @alexolut какое ваше резюме: обсуждалось ли там "миллион людей затронул" vs. "миллион человек затронул"? Кстати—эта цифра имеет значение в основном когда она в миллионах измеряется (если ваше видео имеет 20 просмотров на YouTube—это вероятно не новость. Если миллион—то можно упомянуть и людям, которые о YouTube ничего не знают). Что правила русского языка говорят? Не пытались смотреть?

Comment: Не пытались на одном из сайтов о русском языке на Stack Overflow о "1M людей" vs. "1M человек" спросить? Там этот вопрос человек с хорошим знанием русского языка может увидеть.

Comment: @jfs мой вопрос изначально возник из-за неверной формы фразы при небольших кол-вах людей. Даже не предполагал, что тема так глубока:)

Comment: Этот элемент присутствует на сайте, чтобы опытным участникам наглядно их вклад по порядку величины показать. Что на rus.SO или russian.SO говорят?

Comment: @jfs я пока так не углублялся. Если у Вас есть время, пожалуйста, попробуйте выяснить. Можно будет потом включить это в текущий вопрос.

Comment: @alexolut по-моему, мы об одном и том же. Примерно 21 человек - это значит, что может быть и 19, и 25 человек. Точно никто не знает. Так что значок "~" уместен даже при маленьких числах.

Comment: @NewDevelop т.е. Вы считаете, что из-за `~` можно не соблюдать правильную форму числительного? Например писать `~1 человек затронул`?

Comment: @alexolut безусловно, нет, и не из-за значка "~", а по нормам русского языка.

Comment: https://rg.ru/2016/02/11/kak-govorit-pravilno-chelovek-ili-liudi.html вот пример - с числами правильно употреблять "человек".

Comment: @NewDevelop в любом случае, есть форма `~N people reached` нужно определиться, как её разрешить для всех возможных вариантов `N`  `1-999`, `1-999k`, `1-999m`. Если у Вас есть идеи - пожалуйста, оформите как ответ.

Comment: @NewDevelop [ваша ссылка](https://rg.ru/2016/02/11/kak-govorit-pravilno-chelovek-ili-liudi.html) говорит что нужно именно *люди* использовать так как у нас не *123456 человек*, а *~1m людей*. \@alexolut вы тему подняли—вам на [rus.SO и спрашивать (лучше когда заинтересованное лицо спрашивает)](http://rus.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @jfs заинтересованы тут все, кто участвует в обсуждении :)

Comment: @jfs по ссылке прямо сказано, что если употребляется количество (а примерно один миллион - это тоже количество), то "человек". Если околочислительные существительные (миллионы без числа этих миллионов), то "людей".  Вот есть ещё одна ссылка на rus.SO, в которой сказано, что если нам важно количество, то "человек", а если мы подразумеваем конкретных людей - то "людей". http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416753
Мою точку зрения отражает ответ alexolut, но если мы завели разговор о людях и человеках, то здесь правильно "человек".

Comment: @NewDevelop точное число в нашем случае неизвестно. Буквальная цитата из вашей ссылки: *"Точное обозначение числа - ЧЕЛОВЕК.  Приблизительное обозначение массы - ЛЮДИ."* (первые слова в описании метрики: *estimated number*). В rus.SE ссылке точное число приведено—не наш случай.

Answer (score 10):

Предлагаю использовать форму «человек» повсеместно.

«Затронул 2 тысячи человек» кажется правильнее, чем «Затронул 2 тысячи людей».

Соответственно

- Затронул 31 человека
- Затронул 2 человек
- Затронул 100 человек
- Затронул 201K человек

Comment: Исходя из соображения, что "люди" - uncountable?

Comment: Нужны исключения для чисел 1,2,3,4: "Затронул 1 человека" и т.п.

Comment: @edem в transifex есть возможность задать разные формы для [one/few/many](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1136/176217). В общем, я думаю, придется реализовать что-то подобное кол-ву показов вопросов.

Comment: @edem: Да, добавил.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Скорее из соображений благозвучности. «Затронул 5 людей» моему немецкому уху звучит очень не по-русски.

Comment: Знак `~` предлагается убрать? Не уверен, что получится впихнуть число в середину фразы, т.к. в transifex переменной в явном виде нет, только фраза [`people reached`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266771?q=people%20reached).

Comment: @VladD [NewDevelop привёл ссылку наверху](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3964/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc#comment12884_3964), которая говорит что если если число приблизительное (наш случай), то следует "люди" использовать, а не "человек".

Comment: @jfs `~1 людей` выглядит довольно странно всё же.

Comment: @alexolut Как я уже выше говорил, эта надпись, чтобы поощрить опытных участников (когда речь о тысячах/миллионах). Может быть аргумент, чтобы вообще не показывать значения близкие к нулю:  ~0. Но это не отменяет аргумент, что метрика оценочная, а не точная величина (прочитайте подсказку: _"**Estimated** number of times people viewed.."_)

Comment: @jfs я прекрасно понимаю, что метрика оценочная, но это не отменяет того факта, что запись должна читаться адекватно. Т.е. при N=1 будет `примерно одного человека`, а не `примерно один людей`. Чтобы убрать это поле для малых чисел, надо на meta.se обсуждать уже, а не тут.

Comment: @alexolut значит вы хотите испортить перевод для случая, для которого фраза вводилась для людей, которые затронули миллионы людей, чтобы фраза в случае ~0 "читалась адекватно" для вас?

Comment: @jfs: Моё чувство языка говорит: «затронул 5 миллионов человек», но «затронул миллионЫ людей». То есть в нашем случае нужно именно «человек», как мне кажется: у нас тут указывается конкретное число.

Comment: @jfs я хочу, чтобы запись читалась правильно при **любых** N.

Comment: @VladD: про "конкретное число": в моём комментарии estimated выделено жирным курсивом, а не знаю как ещё сказать, что число ***приблизительное***. Что вы думает `~` перед числом означает?

Comment: @jfs: Я понимаю. Но тем не менее, с тильдой или без, это звучит не по-русски. Русский язык не ориентируется на наличие тильд. Точно так же мне кажется правильным «пришло примерно две тысячи человек», но «пришли тысячи людей». Если вам так не кажется правильным, имеет смысл создать альтернативный ответ.

Comment: @VladD мне всё равно какой результат, если люди информированное решение принимают. Для меня использовать "человек" здесь это всё равно что приводить все 16 цифр из калькулятора в ответе, в котором только пару цифр значащими являются—это демонстрирует безграмотность (кстати, я не знаю точных правил здесь: может технически корректно нужно говорить "затронул порядка 5 тысяч человек" всегда, но я читаю как "затронул тысячи людей" (ниже ожидаемая точность—спросите себя, как это число конкретно вычисляется и какую величину эта метрика призвана оценить).

Comment: @jfs: Я понимаю, что употребление как в моём ответе кажется вам неправильным. И вы, я думаю, понимаете, что употребление как в вашем предложении кажется мне неправильным. Поскольку вы не убедили меня, я не отказываюсь от своего варианта. Поскольку я не убедил вас, я выставил ваш вариант на голосование [отдельным ответом](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3974/10105). Прошу отредактировать его, если я неправильно передал вашу идею.

Comment: @VladD пожалуйста не интерпретируйте мои комментарии. Цитируйте меня буквально. Или задайте вопрос конкретный. В частности, я не вижу где я сказал, что ваш ответ "кажется мне неправильным". Я не пытался вас убеждать. Я изложил некоторые факты, относящиеся к вопросу. Если какой-то мой тезис неверен, то (если хотите) укажите на это, *процитировав его буквально*. В строну: вы уверены что вариант в ответе вообще в систему можно как есть вставить? Чтобы людей в заблуждение не вводить, укажите варианты в ответе как они системой будут отображаться.

Comment: @jfs: Я не знаю тонкостей работы системы, поэтому не могу сказать, можно ли ответ использовать в таком виде, как он есть. Тем не менее, это не означает, что ответ неправильный. Если система не реализцет нужную логику, её нужно исправить.

Comment: @VladD снова: где (приведите ссылку) я употребил слова "ответ неправильный"? (чтобы это не значило в данном контексте)

Comment: @jfs: [Вот](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3964/#comment12885_3965). Я посчитал это (завуалированным) утверждением, что форма, использованная в ответе, не отвечает правилам русского языка.

Comment: @VladD у вас ответ использует *точные* цифры такие как 31  (тильды нет). Если я правильно вас понял, вы хотите изменить текущий формат используемый на сайте, на то что в ответе указано. Для точных цифр ссылка рекомендует "человек" использовать. Более того, как я уже сказал выше, даже если слово "по порядку" добавить в ваш ответ, всё равно вероятно технически "человек" следует использовать. В этом смысле, мой комментарий технически верен, только если *"наш случай"* также как и ваш ответ может потребовать изменения движка (чтобы показывал "затронул тысячи людей" вместо "~5k человек затронул").

Comment: Да нет же, в моей ссылке под обсуждением вопроса говорится, что в данном случае правильно именно "человек", а не людей. Там говорится об употреблении "человек" с числительными и "людей" с существительными. Один миллион - сколько тильд перед ним ни поставь - останется числительным.

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю стараться быть честными—не говорить «затронул 31 человека». Эта метрика—это всего лишь оценка (примерное число). Чтобы лишнего не обещать, можно просто порядок величины указывать:

- Затронул десятки людей
- Затронул сотни людей
- Затронул тысячи людей
- Затронул десятки тысяч людей
- Затронул сотни тысяч людей
- Затронул миллионы людей
- Затронул десятки миллионов людей
- ...

В подсказке можно, конкретное число (просмотры), вычисляемое системой показать, вместе с его определением и ссылкой на используемый алгоритм.

Comment: В такой формулировке мне нравится, да.

Comment: Идея хорошая, но есть пара проблем: на текущий момент такое не обеспечить, если не добавить новых оригинальных строк в transifex, а на это вряд ли пойдут; не так много места в блоке для этих строк.

Comment: @alexolut: Но стоит стремиться к более правильному отображению.

Comment: @VladD суровые реалии придется учитывать.

Comment: Мне меньше нравится такой подход, потому что я отношусь сейчас к пользователям с небольшой полезностью, и приятно иногда заметить, что вот цифра ещё немного увеличилась.

Comment: Если движок мог бы возвращать округленные значения, то слова можно заменить на числа. Это уменьшит горизонтальный размер текста. И не нужно иметь разных форм.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть надо вообще отойти от людей и "человеков", и заменить на "пользователей" или "участников"? То есть, на уже знакомые по сайту понятия.

Comment: А вы уверены, что это именно зарегистрированные участники?  Что-то многовато. Наверное это все же разные заходы (в т.ч. и боты), не знаю точно, как именно их тут различают, наверное по кукам (и их отсутствию).

Comment: @avp исходя из [этого ответа](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1068/176217) я предположил, что "пользователь" это не обязательно зарегистрированный участник.

Comment: Понятно, но по крайней мере по русски, совершенно не интуитивно (не приложите же Вы [подобное разъяснение](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1054/%d0%9c%d1%8b-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8/1068#1068) прямо к термину на страничке (тем более там он сам (наверное в качестве *участника*) именуется *пользователь(!)* (см. заголовок темы))

Answer (score 1):

Если поменять порядок полей, то перевод можно оставить почти без изменений:

> Людей затронул: ~N

Не уверен, что это возможно при текущем подходе к локализации. Как и для некоторых других предложенных ответов.

Comment: @минусатор, причина будет озвучена?