# Перевод для надписей в профиле пользователя

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника, страница-учётной-записи

Заметил отсутствие перевода для блока с кол-вом затронутых людей и полезных тревог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для `people reached` нашел два таких вопроса [один](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11645/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-reached-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5) и [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/447/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-people-reached). И что странно в traducir есть [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/8934) для этой строки. А также для [helpful flags](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17243). Не очень понятно почему при наличии переводов на странице все-равно показывает англ версию.

Comment: Если при наличии переводов в traducir на сайте всё равно их нет, то скорее всего просто строки забыли обернуть в tr() и надо об этом писать на MSE, предварительно убедившись что ситуация актуальна и для других SO: es, pt, ja; а так же для rus.se

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, проблема в том что у меня нет таких надписей, меня ж на этих сайтах нет :( либо попросить участников сообщества которые есть на данных ресурсах чтобы у себя посмотрели, но я не оч в курсе как тут бросается клич для таких действий)

Comment: Так этот блок показывается для любого участника, можно просто в чей-то профиль зайти во вкладку активности. Ну или зарегаться (это бесплатно) и посмотреть.